# Strange interaction between __setitem__ and __get__

Tags: python-2.7

Can anyone explain the following strangeness?

This works as expected:

```
duncan@duncan:~/Working/wtf$ python -V
Python 2.7.3

duncan@duncan:~/Working/wtf$ cat test_without_get.py 
class B(object):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print "__setitem__"

class A(object):
    b = B()

a = A()
a.b
a.b[0] = 1

duncan@duncan:~/Working/wtf$ python test_without_get.py 
__setitem__
```

But here `__setitem__` breaks and appears to call `__get__` in it's place:

```
duncan@duncan:~/Working/wtf$ cat test_with_get.py 
class B(object):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print "__setitem__"
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        print "__get__"

class A(object):
    b = B()

a = A()
a.b
a.b[0] = 1

duncan@duncan:~/Working/wtf$ python test_with_get.py
__get__
__get__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_with_get.py", line 12, in <module>
    a.b[0] = 1
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

does any one have any insight int why this happens
and how to work around it?

---

Further experimentation:

as suggested by ignacio-vazquez-abrams@ ,
if `__get__` returns an object, things work as expected:

```
duncan@dunksbox:~/Working/wtf$ python -V
Python 2.7.3
duncan@dunksbox:~/Working/wtf$ cat test_with_get_working.py 
class B(object):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print "__setitem__"

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        print "__get__"
        return self

class A(object):
    b = B()

a = A()
a.b
a.b[0] = 1

duncan@dunksbox:~/Working/wtf$ python ./test_with_get_working.py 
__get__
__get__
__setitem__
```

but only if you are careful about what `__get__` returns:

```
duncan@dunksbox:~/Working/wtf$ cat test_with_get_notworking.py 
class B(object):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print "__setitem__"

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        print "__get__"
        return [1]

class A(object):
    b = B()

a = A()
a.b
a.b[0] = 1

duncan@dunksbox:~/Working/wtf$ python ./test_with_get_notworking.py 
__get__
__get__
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you've created `B` as a descriptor since it defines one of the descriptor protocol methods. The only ways around it are to either not create it as a descriptor in the first place, or to return a separate object from the descriptor whose `__setitem__()` method behaves as desired.

Comment: yes indeed. as my use case requires using B() as a descriptor, returning an object works.
(see my further snippets in original post for further experimentation.)